# UWP 10 C#. Reading a text file into a List<>

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Let me start by saying that I'm brand new to UWP and the closest I have come to this language would be C++ about 12 years ago!

I'm writing an app for Windows Universal and in it I'll be reading different text files in line by line, split the contents of each line (Some files I won't need to split the line), add the data into a list and then show it on screen.  I've tried many ways to do this but I haven't got it working correctly. I currently have two methods that are working, but not consistently. It will show the data but only sometimes. When I run the app (either in emulator or on local device) it may or may not show the data and then if I click to a different page and back into the list page, it may or may not show it again..

Here's the code.. In this case I'm splitting the contents of the text file into 3 strings splitting on a '-'

in my XAML.cs file

```
public sealed partial class SPList : Page
{
    private List<ThreeColumnList> ThreeColumnLists;
    public SPList()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ThreeColumnLists = ThreeColumnListManager.GetList();
    }
}
```

in my XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="TrackingAssistant.SPList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TrackingAssistant"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:TrackingAssistant.Model"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- x:DataType="<Name Of Class>" -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ThreeColumnListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:ThreeColumnList">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind Job}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                   Name="ResultTextBlock" 
                   FontSize="24" 
                   Foreground="Red" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                   Margin="20,20,0,0" />
        <!--  ItemsSource="x:Bind <Variable from the CS(Code) Class>   -->
        <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ThreeColumnLists}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThreeColumnListDataTemplate}">
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

in ThreeColumnList.cs

```
class ThreeColumnList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
}
```

In my ThreeColumnListManager.cs

```
class ThreeColumnListManager
{
    public static List<ThreeColumnList> GetList()
    {
        var threecolumnlists = new List<ThreeColumnList>();

        //Add a dummy row to present something on screen
        threecolumnlists.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = "Name1", Age = "Age1", Job = "Job1" });

        //First working method
        readList(threecolumnlists);

        //Second Working Method
        //tryAgain(threecolumnlists);

        return threecolumnlists;
    }

    public static async void readList(List<ThreeColumnList> tcl)
    {
        List<ThreeColumnList> a = tcl;
        string _line;
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Lists/splist.txt"));
        using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
        {
            while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Line");
                _line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("the line is {0}", _line ));
                string _first = "" + _line.Split('-')[0];
                string _second = "" + _line.Split('-')[1];
                string _third = "" + _line.Split('-')[2];

                a.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = _first, Age = _second, Job = _third });
            }
        }
    }

    public static async void tryAgain(List<ThreeColumnList> tcl)
    {
        //Loading Folder
        var _folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync("Lists");

        //Get the file
        var _file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("splist.txt");

        // read content
        IList<string> _ReadLines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(_file);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var _line in _ReadLines)
        {
            i++;
            string _first = "" + _line.Split('-')[0];
            string _second = "" + _line.Split('-')[1];
            string _third = "" + _line.Split('-')[2];
            tcl.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = _first, Age = _second, Job = _third });
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Count is " + i);
    }
}
```

And in this case with the file being split into three, a sample of the text file would look like this

```
Bloggs, Joe-25-Engineer
Flynn, John-43-Assistant
Sherriff, Patsy-54-Manager
!-!-!
```

The line !-!-! is a seperator line but it will still display ! ! ! on screen after splitting on the -

Initially I was trying to grab the contents of the file and return them to GetList() and process the contents into the List there but I was having no luck.

Then I decided to try pass the list to the method that grabs the content and populate the List there.

Both the functions I have do display content to the screen but not consistently. ReadList() seems to work more frequently that tryAgain() but it still does not work every time.

Also, just to note, I've tried this where I'm not splitting the contents of each line of the file and I'm seeing the same issue where it will load only sometimes.

[I was following this video to get the initial list working](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls). Once I got this working then I moved onto reading in from file.

I have a feeling that I'm really close but I'm not sure.

Anyone any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can show (a part of)  the input file?

Comment: @sybren Sorry yes! I had meant to add that! I've updated the post now with a sample. I also have tried this where I'm not splitting each line in the file, I'm only using one column and I'm getting the same result where it only works sometimes. The data in that text file would be just like any text file with new lines in it. Thanks!

Comment: I debug your code and works fine. I believe on the code part you are fine. What worries me is the xaml part. How do you dispay your data??  Can you add the xaml part and how you pass the data in the elements?

Comment: @Stamos I've updated with post with my XAML now and also with [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls) of the tutorial I was following to implement a list. Once I got that working then I moved onto the reading in from file part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection interfaces that are used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

Also use Task to load the data.

Edit:

MainPage.cs.xaml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace TestUWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> threeColumnLists;

        public ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> ThreeColumnLists
        {
            get { return threeColumnLists ?? (threeColumnLists = new ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList>()); }
            set { threeColumnLists = value; }
        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();

        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            //you can also change the private threeColumnLists to a static 
            // and do 
            //if(ThreeColumnLists.Count==0) 
            //   ThreeColumnLists = await ThreeColumnListManager.GetListAsync();
            ThreeColumnLists = await ThreeColumnListManager.GetListAsync();
            //can also do
            // await ThreeColumnListManager.readList(ThreeColumnLists);
        }

    }

    public class ThreeColumnList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name = string.Empty;
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

        private string age = string.Empty;
        public string Age { get { return age; } set { age = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Age"); } }

        private string job = string.Empty;
        public string Job { get { return job; } set { job = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Job"); } }

        //PropertyChanged handers
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
    public class ThreeColumnListManager
    {
        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList>> GetListAsync()
        {
            var threecolumnlists = new ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList>();

            //Add a dummy row to present something on screen
            threecolumnlists.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = "Name1", Age = "Age1", Job = "Job1" });

            //First working method
            await readList(threecolumnlists);

            //Second Working Method
            //tryAgain(threecolumnlists);

            return threecolumnlists;
        }

        public static async Task readList(ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> tcl)
        {
            string _line;
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Lists/slplist.txt"));
            using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
            {
                while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Line");
                    _line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("the line is {0}", _line ));
                    string _first = "" + _line.Split('-')[0];
                    string _second = "" + _line.Split('-')[1];
                    string _third = "" + _line.Split('-')[2];

                    tcl.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = _first, Age = _second, Job = _third });
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task tryAgain(ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> tcl)
        {
            //Loading Folder
            var _folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync("Lists");

            //Get the file
            var _file = await _folder.GetFileAsync("splist.txt");

            // read content
            IList<string> _ReadLines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(_file);

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var _line in _ReadLines)
            {
                i++;
                string _first = "" + _line.Split('-')[0];
                string _second = "" + _line.Split('-')[1];
                string _third = "" + _line.Split('-')[2];
                tcl.Add(new ThreeColumnList { Name = _first, Age = _second, Job = _third });
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Count is " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="TestUWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestUWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <!-- x:DataType="<Name Of Class>" -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ThreeColumnListDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:ThreeColumnList">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Age}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind Job}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Name="ResultTextBlock" 
               FontSize="24" 
               Foreground="Red" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               Margin="20,20,0,0" />
    <!--  ItemsSource="x:Bind <Variable from the CS(Code) Class>   -->
    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ThreeColumnLists}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThreeColumnListDataTemplate}">
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks but I'm having issues if you could help. Initially I had issues in the `SPList.xaml.cs` file but I found a solution online to changed `public ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> ThreeColumnLists` to `private` this resolved that issue. Then I had an issue in the XAML but this was because the I was using a different list name in my previous code so I updated it to point to `threeColumnLists`. After this change I could build & run, but when I click into the page to load the list the app crashed.It is showing that it can not find SPList when it tries to load the new page.Any idea?

Comment: Dont change the `public ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> ThreeColumnLists` to private. Make sure `xmlns:data="using:TrackingAssistant.Model"` and `<DataTemplate x:Key="ThreeColumnListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:ThreeColumnList">
` are pointing to the correct place.

Comment: I added my full Solution with the output check this out to find what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I created a new project with the code and I can see that every time I compile with just this code, it loads in the list perfectly. Then I added a second page and changed the App.xaml.cs to load the new page first. This page just has a button on it so I can navigate to the list page. I also added button to the list page to go back the new page and now I find that when I load and click between the pages, it loads the list approx 80% of the time. The other times it just loads a blank page. Any reason that it wouldn't load every time? I'm starting to wonder if its emulator related.

Comment: Do you add or remove lines in the txt file?? If yes, you are doing in in the app of from another app??. And if no change `private ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> threeColumnLists;` to `private static ObservableCollection<ThreeColumnList> threeColumnLists;` just uncomment the lines i have in my code and comment the `ThreeColumnLists = await ThreeColumnListManager.GetListAsync();` that way it will load the list once and keep it in the memory and each time you navigate to the page the list will be there

Comment: Ah excellent! That has helped and solved! The txt file won't ever be altered by the app itself, its just required to present the data on screen. I've made the changes as you suggested and I can see it is working much better now! Thanks very much! I'll go through your code again and make sure I fully understand what's happening now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `await` or `Wait()` on `Task`.

Change signature from
`public static async void readList(List<ThreeColumnList> tcl)`
to
`public static async Task readList(List<ThreeColumnList> tcl)`
And invoke it like `readList(threecolumnlists).Wait();`

This breaks asynchrony of your code, but will work.
The best way would be to change `GetList()` to be async and run this in Task showing spinner or progress bar to user:

```
public SPList()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        ThreeColumnLists = await ThreeColumnListManager.GetList();
        IsLoading = false;
    }
}

private bool _isLoading;
public bool IsLoading
{
    get { return _isLoading; }
    set
    {
        if(_isLoading != value)
        {
            _isLoading = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsLoading));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
First I tried with the `.Wait()` method. When I tried to run the application after this change, Once I clicked on the button to load the file, it would just hang.
I then changes `GetList()` as you suggested and this is working a lot better. But it still not loading every time. It will successfully load about 80% of the time which is a huge improvement. `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsLoading));` Is showing an exception in my code on `PropertyChanged?` so for now I've commented this out. Any ideas why it still won't work every time??
Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that when the data doesn't load in fully, it's not even showing the dummy row thats is coded into the list on screen now. So it's almost like now it seems to have a problem with the list<> but not the text file!...

Comment: For `PropertyChanged` to work your class need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score -2):

Going out on a limb here but:

The async operation means it can be run on a different thread so it's possible that the end result of reading the file (a list of ThreeColumnList) is living on a different thread. Do you receive (or have you suppressed) exceptions that occur during or shortly after loading a file? You might consider double-checking that you are marshalling the list to the UI thread before binding occurs if it's owner thread is not the UI thread to avoid this issue.