# How to apply lazy loading to bing ListView in windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am working on Sales App of Windows Store app. I want to apply lazy loading for my product module.

When Product page open it get product from backend and show in ListBox control.
It takes time everytime to load. I think main reason is when I check for the image exists on given url.

Here is my code and class:

```
private async Task getAllProductDetails()
{
    var resultproductlist = await client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/magemobpos/product/getProductList", contents);
    if (resultproductlist.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string trys = resultproductlist.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        List<Productlistdata> objProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductlistResponse>(trys).productlistdata;
        Productlistdata Product;

        //all product are in objProducts
        foreach (var item in objProducts)
        {
            bool imageexist = false;
            //check if image exist on given url or not
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(item.image.ToString()));
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
                {

                    int imagelength = Convert.ToInt32(response.ContentLength);
                    if (imagelength > 0)
                        imageexist = true;
                    else
                        imageexist = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                imageexist = false;
            }

            //if image not exist, it get default image
            if (item.image.ToString().ToLower().Equals("n/a") || imageexist == false)
            {
                item.image = "Images/NoDataImages/ico-no-orders.png";
            }

            Product = new Productlistdata()
            {
                image = item.image,
                name = item.name,
                price = item.price,
                sku = item.sku,
                type = item.type[0],
                id = item.id
            };
            //add all product in lstProduct. lstProduct is ListBox Control
            lstProduct.Items.Add(Product);      
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Productlistdata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string full_productname { get; set; }
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how to apply lazy loading? I don't know exactly but I think it can apply to bind image once the list is loaded.

Comment: I haven't worked on a windowsRT or UWP app, however both are based on WPF/Silverlight and they do lazy loading by default, in which case the problem is your model

Comment: @MikeT It's not WPF or Silverlight app. It's Windows Store App. Can you suggest me changes in Model and call of `imageexist` in my code?

Comment: Windows Store App's use either windowsRT  or UWP depending if they are windows 8 or 10 based, and both of them use a variation of WPF and Silverlight. my point was that while i haven't got specific knowledge on that the variation you are using but i can provide general information that will hopefully helf

Comment: I would check out Lance McCarthy's UWP Git https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/UwpProjects He has a free lazy load control in his collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you dint ask for it but I ll strongly suggest you to look into [Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) I believe it will help you a lot thinking what you are trying to build. So I ll start by changing some of your code using bindings and then go to the real solution.

Here is what you can try and do:

First remove this code:

```
bool imageexist = false;
        //check if image exist on given url or not
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(item.image.ToString()));
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {

                int imagelength = Convert.ToInt32(response.ContentLength);
                if (imagelength > 0)
                    imageexist = true;
                else
                    imageexist = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            imageexist = false;
        }
```

Second Step is to get rid of this code

```
//add all product in lstProduct. lstProduct is ListBox Control
lstProduct.Items.Add(Product);
```

Now add on top of you page.xaml.cs an ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<Productlistdata> productlist = new ObservableCollection<Productlistdata>();

    public ObservableCollection<Productlistdata> Productlist
    {
        get { return productlist ?? (productlist= new ObservableCollection<Productlistdata>()); }
        set { productlist= value; }
    }
```

Now you either bind that list in the list box like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Productlist}"/>
```

or In the Contractor of your page do

```
lstProduct.ItemsSource = Productlist;
```

That way Productlist is binded to your ListBox and when you add or remove items will it will be updated automatically.

Now you can skip all the above but I suggest you to look into [Bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) it powerfull and will solve many of your problems when you get the idea of they work.

Now we will add the first code we removed in your ProductListdata

```
public class Productlistdata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string full_productname { get; set; }

    public async void CheckImage()
    {
        bool imageexist = false;
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(image));
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
            {

                int imagelength = Convert.ToInt32(response.ContentLength);
                if (imagelength > 0)
                    imageexist = true;
                else
                    imageexist = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            imageexist = false;
        }
        if (!imageexist)
        {
            image = "Images/NoDataImages/ico-no-orders.png";
        }
    }
}
```

And populate your List

```
private async Task getAllProductDetails()
    {
        var resultproductlist = await client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/magemobpos/product/getProductList", contents);
        if (resultproductlist.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string trys = resultproductlist.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<Productlistdata> objProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductlistResponse>(trys).productlistdata;


            //all product are in objProducts
            foreach (var item in objProducts)
            {
                Productlistdata Product = new Productlistdata()
                {
                    image = item.image,
                    name = item.name,
                    price = item.price,
                    sku = item.sku,
                    type = item.type[0],
                    id = item.id
                };
                Product.CheckImage();
                Productlist.Add(Product);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Product.CheckImage();` will not be awaited. So the Items in the list will load really fast because nothing is awaited in the foreach loop. `Product.CheckImage();` will run on another thread at later time.

Finally because image might change after the data is loaded on the ListBoxa(when image wasnt fount) you will have to Notify the UI that a property has changed. To do that you will have to use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx). You can take a look in an other answer of mine how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779366/2520974)

Comment: Stamos, It is working fast by doesn't change image later.

Comment: @NinjiMange read the last paragraph in my answer. That is why I strogly suggest you to use bindgings with 'INotifyPropertChanged'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your queries,

firstly instead of getAllProductDetails do getAllProductID
so where you have

```
        var resultproductlist = await client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/magemobpos/product/getProductList", contents);
        if (resultproductlist.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string trys = resultproductlist.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<Productlistdata> objProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductlistResponse>(trys).productlistdata;
            Productlistdata Product;
```

you would do

```
        var resultproductlist = await client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/magemobpos/product/getProductID", contents);
        if (resultproductlist.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string trys = resultproductlist.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<int> objProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductlistResponse>(trys).productlistdata;
            LazyProductlistdata Product;
```

secondly create a wrapper

```
public LazyProductlistdata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    private Lazy<Productlistdata> data = new Lazy<Productlistdata>(()=>Productlistdata.CreateFromID(id));
    public Productlistdata Data
    {
       get{return data.Value;}
    }
}
```

expand this so the wrapper contains information required for sorting

finally alter the constructor or create a factory for Productlistdata so that it obtains the individual record from the source

```
public class Productlistdata
{
    public static Productlistdata CreateFromID(int id)
    {
         //Return single Productlistdata from webservice
    }
}
```

NOTE: lazy loading will increase the overall load time, the advantange is that instead of it being 1 huge block of time its several smaller ones

Comment: Can you please suggest me changes in call flow of getAllProductID() and getAllProductDetails()?

Comment: hard to be precise as most of the changes are in the web service that you haven't supplied

Comment: Well, I just get list of call. I can just supply parameter and call for result. Let me try your approach.

Comment: Mike, Do I need to keep try..catch of "//check if image exist" as it is?

Comment: depends if its likely to error, as you are using a web request then there is always a chance of network issues, so i would say yes

Comment: you can also do the lazy load on the image to, so where you have public string image { get; set; } you can change to Lazy<string> image;  and have the Lazy factory action calling the image service

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Converter to supply placeholder [see here](http://www.markermetro.com/2011/06/technical/mvvm-placeholder-images-for-failed-image-load-on-windows-phone-7-with-caliburn-micro/).

You can also decorate Image.Source binding with IsAsync = True - so that main thread would not be blocked

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageFailed event to assign image placeholder

```
foreach (var item in objProducts)
{
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.ImageFailed += (s, e) => bitmap.UriSource = defaultImageUri;
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(item.image);
item.Add(bitmap);
//set decodepixelwidth and dicodepixelheight correctly to avoid outofmemory exception
}
```